# how to reset Rhinoslider Jquery plugin without page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the jquery code below

```
$('#slider').rhinoslider({
            effect: 'kick',

            autoPlay:'true',
            showTime: 200,
});
```

i want to reset rhinoslider jquery and change slider effect
without refreshing the page

Comment: always post the link to the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/fLayL852/)?

Steps

1. Clone the slider `ul` before initializing and save it in a variable
2. Initialize the plugin
3. When you want to update, delete the existing slider
4. Append the cloned copy to `body` or any dom element
5. Re-initialize the slider
6. PROFIT.!!!

**CODE** (for code in action check the fiddle)

```
var slides = $('#slideshow').clone();
$('#slideshow').rhinoslider();

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.rhino-container').remove();
    $('body').append(slides);
    $('#slideshow').rhinoslider({effect:"explode"});
})
```

Comment: i m not tested yet but from jquery knowledge it will work

Comment: you should accept/upvote if you find the answer useful.